# Looped signal handling for UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, signals

I have a loop in my `main()` that will continue until the stop signal (ctrl z) or quit (ctrl ) is obtained.
Loop:

```
signal(SIGQUIT, signalHandler);
signal(SIGTSTP, signalHandler);
while (1)
    sleep(1);
```

What I want to do is when I receive a ctrl z signal, in addition to printing out "Stop received", is that I want my program to actually stopped.
Current signal Handler function:

```
void signalHandler(int signum) {
    if (signum == SIGQUIT)
        cout << "Quit recieved" << endl;
        break;
    else if (signum == SIGTSTP)
        cout << "Stop recieved" << endl;
        break;
    else {
        cout << "SOMETHING'S WRONG" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

What do I need to add in order for me to do this (this being that the stop signal is received and will stop my program)? What I've tried so far is putting `raise(SIGTSTP)` in my `signalHandler` function, but that puts me in an infinite loop. I've also tried creating a `volatile sig_atomic_t`, initializing it to 0, but it never updates for me once a signal is received (it stays at 0).

Comment: What do you mean "stop"?  Stop as in end the program or stop as in the program is suspended?

Comment: Stop as in suspend the program.

Comment: When you catch SIGTSTP, raise(SIGSTOP) - not inside the handler.

Comment: Figured out a solution. What I did was that I moved my signal() calls into the while loop, and when SIGTSTP is received, I put another signal() so that the next SIGTSTP read is dealt with the default way (stops the program), and then did raise(SIGTSTP) to stop the program.

Comment: That will work but SIGSTOP will stop your pgm.  You can't catch it.